# Drupel 9, GD not enabled

Tags: linux, php, linux-networking, database, web-hosting

I have for hours been attempting to set up a Drupel database, but have been stumped on this error message:

"PHP extensions
Disabled
Drupal requires you to enable the PHP extensions in the following list (see the system requirements page for more information):

- gd"

I have tried various things to enable it, but nothing would work. And after all of this, I went to check info.php to see if it said anything, and the gd category wasn't even there! Where do I go from here? I am screwed? Thanks in advance.
[Picture of gd not being in info.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XJqh.png)
[Picture of gd conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM9R3.png)

Edit, I felt it would be important to mention I am using the latest version of Linux Mint, 20.1

The file I installed is named php-gd8.0.

Comment: Did you restart the server after attempting to enable GD?

Comment: I have several times, but to no avail. I used the command "systemctl restart apache2".

Comment: Have you actually installed it?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the file php-gd8.0